# Using linq select to provide a grid datasource, properties are read-only

Tags: c#-3.0

I am using the return from the following call as the datasource for a grid.
        `public object GetPropertyDataSourceWithCheckBox( )
        {
            return (
                from p in LocalProperties
                join c in GetCities( ) on p.CityID equals c.CityID
                orderby p.StreetNumber
                select new { Selected = false, p.PropertyID, p.StreetNumber, p.StreetName, c.CityName } ).ToList( );
        }`

I get a checkbox in the grid, but it is READ-ONLY. [For the record, the grid is DevExpress.]  Is there a way around this, short of creating a non-anonymous class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing research tells me that, in fact, anonymous classes returned by linq are always read-only, so, apparently, creating an actual class is best (only?) solution.